# Why does SPI.transfer() freeze the second time I call it?

Tags: c, arduino, spi, xbee

I'm trying to learn how to get an Arduino to talk to an XBee PRO S3B module via SPI. As sort of a hello world, I figured I would try to read some information about the XBee module's configuration (specifically, its DL setting). Reading this information requires first sending an 8-byte length command through SPI.

I use the `SPI.transfer()` function of the Arduino SPI library to send the command one byte at a time. It looks like I am able to send the first byte just fine -- the problem is that the code seems to freeze on the second time I call `SPI.transfer()`.

In my code, I have the data of the command stored in a byte array called `AT_getDL_CMD`, whose length (8) is stored in `AT_getDL_LEN`. Here is the relevant part of the code:

```
  // start the SPI library:
  SPI.beginTransaction(SPISettings(3000000, MSBFIRST, SPI_MODE0));

  // initalize the pins:
  pinMode(SPI_ATTN, INPUT);
  pinMode(SPI_SSEL, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(SPI_SSEL, LOW);

  // wait a little bit for the radio to be ready:
  delay(1000);

  Serial.println("Sending getDL API command");
  for (int i = 0; i < AT_getDL_LEN; i++) {
    Serial.print(SPI.transfer(AT_getDL_CMD[i]));
    Serial.print(", ");
  }
```

The output I get from this is:

> Sending getDL API command
>
> 0,

So it looks like the loop runs for one iteration but then freezes when it calls `SPI.transfer()` on the second iteration.

What could be causing this? Is it more likely to be a problem on the Arduino's end, or on the XBee's end? Am I using the SPI library incorrectly?

Comment: It's for sure on the Arduino's end, the SPI bus doesn't have any acknowledge / handshake mechanism. You can transmit even if there is no slave device on the other end (and will receive garbage in this case - logical state of MISO pin).

Comment: Any reason it could be seizing when I call SPI.transfer() then?

Comment: I had a look here https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/SPI and it seems there is also `SPI.begin();` Try calling this before the loop.

Comment: Thanks! Looks like that fixed it. I was assuming begin() and beginTransaction() both did the same thing. Now I need to figure out what the difference is (and what the difference between end() and endTransaction() is)